# How to get the following output?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to get the following output ?

**Input:**

```
t1
-----------------
col1    col2
----------------
2        a
1        c
3        b
----------------
```

**Output:**

```
t1
-----------------
col1        col2
----------------
1           a
2           b
3           c
----------------
```

Comment: Where does `b` in the output come from?

Comment: This might help your: [Sort two columns with different ordering](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Oracle/0040__Query-Select/Sorttwocolumnswithdifferentordering.htm)

Comment: this is the craziest question I've seen in the last time. It's really funny for me.

Comment: You should give some background, because what you are asking doesn't make much sense. If you need to sort the columns separately from each other, then the two columns shouldn't be in the same table in the first place.

Comment: @HarryJoy, there's no way a simple list of columns in an order by will produce the results requested by the OP.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp yeah, I also figured that out 10 minutes after posting  that link. :)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using row number like:

```
SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY a.col2) as col1, col2
FROM t1 a ORDER BY a.col2
```

Comment: I've understood differently the problem, as he asks for reorder the thow coloumn separatedly. You just reassign id. :) Don't know which is what the OP asks.

Comment: While I agree with Florin that the question is not unambiguously specified, I suspect Harry's interpretation is most likely the correct one - they just want to "reorder" the id's in the table. The other interpretation just doesn't make any sense anyway.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  C1.col1, C2.col2
from
  (select col1, row_number() over (order by col1) rn
  from t1) C1
join 
  (select col2, row_number() over (order by col2) rn
  from t1) C2
on C1.rn=C2.rn
order by C1.rn
```

Comment: `a.rn` should be `t1.rn` (and with `your_table`, you are referring to OP's `t1`, right? Probably better use other table aliases than `t1/t2`).

Comment: One additional minor correction: `from t2` should be `from t1` (OP's table) - then, it works like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

I think following query may help you.

```
SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY col1 ;
```

please check this link for more practice

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/2e3e9/1/0

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
select col1,col2 from
(select col1,rownum rn from(select col1 from t1 order by col1)) a,
(select col2,rownum rn from(select col2 from t1 order by col2)) b
where a.rn=b.rn
```